# Angular2. Extending Input decorator

Tags: angular

Quite often I need to use stream of input values in component. Usually I do it in this way:

```js
export class UserComponent {
    userId$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);
    @Input() set userId(value: number) {
       this.userId$.next(value);
    }
}
```

I wonder is there a way to create `Input$` decorator:

```js
export class UserComponent {
    @Input$() userId$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you could create additional decorator which will replace class field with getter/setter pair, getter will return `Subject` and setter will do `next` on this subject.

Please note that it will likely break AOT compilation.

```
@Input()
@Reactive(false)
public subject:Subject<boolean>; //you don't even need to initialize

export function Reactive(initialValue:any):Function
{
    return function(target:Object, property:string)
    {
        const name:string = `__subject_${property}`;

        Object.defineProperty(target, name, <PropertyDescriptor>{
            enumerable  : false,
            configurable: false,
            writable    : true
        });

        Object.defineProperty(target, property, <PropertyDescriptor>{
            enumerable  : true,
            configurable: false,
            get         : function():any
            {
                if(this[name] === undefined)
                {
                    this[name] = new BehaviorSubject<any>(initialValue);
                }
                return this[name];
            },
            set         : function(val:any):void
            {
                if(this[name] === undefined)
                {
                    this[name] = new BehaviorSubject<any>(initialValue);
                }
                this[name].next(val);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great, thank you. Can you elaborate, why you think it will break AoT?

Comment: Type checking is more strict in AOT mode and attempt to assign i.e. string value to Subject<string> field may fail. In order to preserve compatibility it makes sense to create decorator for automatic binding input to existing subject, i.e. `@Input() @Reactive<UserComponent>(x => x.subject) bool:boolean;`